# RewriteRule redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Okay I have this RewriteRule which is supposed to redirect any request for the file base.css to {folder of .htacces file}/include/style/base.css, but is just keeps redirecting in an infinite loop, I thought the L parameter would make sure that wouldn't happen.

```
RewriteRule (.*)/base.css$ include/style/base.css [L,NC,R=301]
```

Also it redirects to http://localhost/C:/somemaps/include/style/base.css which it isn't really supposed to do either.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Also I would like to have the RewriteRule so it would redirect any file.css to {folder of .htacces file}/include/style/file.css
BTW the .htacces file is in the root of the website (which is not the root of the server!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Redirect and Rewrite confused.  A redirect is a HTTP status code that tells the browser to go to another URL.  You actually just want to Rewrite the location to another file location.  Try

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*).css$ /include/style/$2.css [L,NC]
```

If this doesn't work try adding the following right after the RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /my-virtual-folder-path-where-htaccess-is-stored
```

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific, about what is not working.  You may have to use RewriteBase to get the correct path to the /include/style file.

Answer (score 2):

> Also I would like to have the RewriteRule so it would redirect any file.css to {folder of .htacces file}/include/style/file.css

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+).css$ /include/style/$1.css [L,NC]
```

Comment: And note that you're *rewriting* the URL (chaning how Apache processes), not *redirecting* it (telling the browser it has moved). That's a crucial difference in understanding mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

This R=301 makes a new request. Therefor it evaluates the RewriteRule again.

Try to exclude this path/directory with a rewrite condition (RewriteCond).

Comment: I don't think he was trying to do a redirect, because it wouldn't make any sense to redirect a style sheet file.  I think he just wanted a plain old physical file path rewrite.